# USB Power Cable Only

Tags: usb

I have the following device:
[image]
http://www.delock.de/produkte/G_61883/merkmale.html?setLanguage=en

The two connectors, when plugged in a USB 2.0 port should output 1A which is enough to power on any hdd. I am very certain that the second connector (2.0 power) has only two wired connections: *vcc* and *gnd*. Without *data+* and *data-*, the device can only draw 100mA. So instead of the 1A, it outputs only ~600mA.

**Is there any way to make draw the maximum ammount (500mA) even if it does not have *data+/data-*?**

**I was thinking of an USB extender cable, with *data+* and *data-* spliced, in order to fool the computer to get 500mA off the port. Would this work?**

Thank you

Comment: Have you actually measured the draw? The USB 100mA rule is ignored 99.5% of the time.

Comment: How did you come by those numbers particularly the 100ma.  Did you use an actual power meter?  Did you go into the Device Manager under USB devices?  Each USB 2 port can provide up to 500ma.  How many **ma** does the hdd your attaching draw.  Dedicated charging port, the D+ and D− pins are shorted with a resistance not exceeding 200 ohms for charging port ONLY mode.  Did you check inside the USB plug to see if those pairs are shorted together thus, charging mode.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't matter with the data wires (D+,D-) in order to draw power from a computer USB 2.0 port so far. There is no mechanism or protocol to communicate for the power supply on computers' USB 2.0/3.0 ports. General speaking, the power output capability of USB 2.0/3.0 ports is defined by USB BC(Battery Charging) v1.2 standard, which there are two type of definitions SDP (up to 500mA) and CDP (up to 1.5A). Most of the computer manufactures are applying SDP for less costs. So it's normal that a computer USB port can only supply less than 1A power.

In your case, the USB 2.0 port is designed to draw extra power from another USB port in case you do not have enough power supply on one port(USB 3.0 one) to power the external HDD. Normally for a 2.5" HDD or a new 3.5" HDD, the power should be enough for it's up to run. But for older aged 3.5" HDD, it may need more power. Then the best solution is to get a separated USB charger (better 2A output) for power supply. It may damage your computer if you try to force power out from the USB port.

Comment: “There is no mechanism or protocol to communicate for the power supply on computers' USB 2.0/3.0 ports.” [But there is.](http://www.beyondlogic.org/usbnutshell/usb5.shtml#DeviceDescriptors) Of course most manufacturers don’t bother to actually limit the current. // You wouldn’t *by any chance* happen to be affiliated with QooPow?

Comment: Yes, I am the inventor of qualMeter.

Comment: Cool. However, [the acceptable behavior guide](http://superuser.com/help/behavior) says you must disclose your affiliation in your answer.

Comment: Okay, I see. Thanks for letting me know! so what do I do? Would it work if I just delete the URL?

Comment: BTW, the USB device descriptors you showed me is for data transmission. They have nothing to do with power output definition nor negotiation. However, it's been changed now after USB PD standard came out.

Comment: You can keep the link. You just need to disclose the affiliation. // The Battery Charging spec defines *new* port types, it doesn’t replace anything. Most ports are *not* charging ports, so power negotiation is still required.

Comment: I am back now. :) Okay, so I'll continue with the conversation we are having here. Power negotiation, yes and no, for what we are mainly talking about in this post, the computer ports, most of them for now they don't have yet. Unless they have been applied with USB PD. Otherwise, you can pull power out from computer USB ports up to its designed limitation until it shuts down(if there is protection) or damage the computer.

Comment: For dedicated USB power ports (not computer USB ports), only some Fast Charging chargers have power negotiation such as QC 1.0/2.0/3.0, MTK PE 1.0/plus/3.0, USB PD and some others. Apple are currently using USB PD with their new Macbooks. Others, like Apple 1A/2.1A/2.4A charging, SAMSUNG 2.0A charging, BC 1.2 DCP charging etc., do not have power negotiation. They only simply use resistors to divide a pair of specific voltages on the D+/D- lines to identify themselves as certain type of charger. This is just a very simple one way communication. Not negotiation at all.

Comment: “you can pull power out from computer USB ports up to its designed limitation until it shuts down” – You can. But the standard says you **must not**. And that’s been my point the whole time.

Comment: You are right, the "must not" is for safety reason. So if you want to draw power out of the Computer's USB port, you need to use it with caution.  Because the USB port was not initially defined to provide big current. And there was no so called power negotiation on the computer's USB ports until USB PD standard showed up recently. FYI, different manufactures have different power supply design over they USB ports. My DELL desktop has 1.5A capability (tested) on it's USB ports. So it highly depends on the MB manufactures for how much power you can pull from the computer USB ports, not by stds.

Comment: But that’s wrong. The power negotiation has been part of USB since the very start. It’s part of the device descriptor. No amount of arguing will change that.

Comment: That's what I was trying to correct you. I think you mix up the concepts. Even if the so called "power negotiation" was there, how could it coexist with data transmission? You just simply cannot apply "power negotiation" signal with data transmission together on the D+/D-. Otherwise your USB data connection would be interrupt at any time and would not be able to transfer data! That's why USB PD uses different mechanism in order to negotiate power delivery by not using the data lines.So, again! There was no so called power negotiation on the computer's USB ports until USB PD showed up recently.

Comment: And there is no such descriptor which is related to power negotiation in the linked page you've provided, if you have read through them one by one. Please show me the descriptor if I was wrong.  :)

Comment: I’m not mixing up concepts. That’s you. Power negotiation is power negotiation, whether it’s done via USB protocol signalling, custom resistor networks or any other protocol, really. The field is called “bMaxPower”. Search for it.

Comment: OK, maybe that's my English problem then. To my limited knowledge on the vocabulary. Negotiation is different with Recognition. Negotiation to me means there has to be an inquiry and answering back, a 2-way communication. Recognition means to recognize a tag or mark, a 1-way communication. Whatever, the descriptor “bMaxPower” or custom resistor networks are just tags to my understanding. They are not negotiating how much of power should be applied on both end. They just simply identify themselves that "I provides this much power". If this sounds to you as negotiation, then be it. lol~

Comment: It’s not recognition (okay, in dumb plug PSUs, it is). The device advertises its operating modes, which include power requirements. The PC then selects a suitable mode – or none, if there is not enough power available.

Comment: That's what I have been trying to tell you. What you've described does apply to the new USB PD supported ports. However, it doesn't happen on non-USB PD ports on computers. There is no such communication because they (USB 1.0/2.0/3.0) were just simply not designed that way when they were born. :)

Comment: No. It does *not* apply to PD. It *only* applies to “regular” data connections. Please read [this article](http://janaxelson.com/usbcenum.htm) on how USB devices are found and activated. [This section](http://www.beyondlogic.org/usbnutshell/usb2.shtml#PowerVbus) on power limits is also of interest.

Comment: So your recommended article again proves that there is no communication between device and host for power negotiation. There are definitions and design guides that try to regulate the USB devices to follow the rule not to drain too much power. But there is nothing to talk about how to communicate (negotiate) in order to apply the rules. Especially in the section on power limits, you cannot do nothing if the device didn't follow the rules. Why? Because there is no such power negotiation to actually monitor and maintain the rules to be obeyed!  :)

Answer (score 0):

Then you will have to use some separate power supply for USB (e.g. a wall outlet-to-USB voltage converter) and not a USB port on a laptop or PC.

I don't think you will be able to fool the enumeration because the device and vendor id would be the same on both ports.